# Using synchronized() in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a android project and am using wait() and notify() so certain code executes only after a background task,this is a function that makes calls to firebase:

```
//Code Snippet 1
 public  Task<String> checkIfJokeSavedFirebase() throws InterruptedException {
        final String[] idToken = {""};
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mUser.getIdToken(true)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            idToken[0] = task.getResult().getToken();
                            data.put("token", idToken[0]);
                            String someObject = "test";
                            synchronized (someObject) {
                                Log.d("longdebug","someObject pre notify");
                                someObject.notify();
                            }
                            //notify();
                            // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            // Handle error -> task.getException();
                        }
                    }
                });
        String someObject = "test";
        synchronized (someObject){
            Log.d("longdebug","someObject pre wait");
            someObject.wait();
        }
        Log.d("runtimeexception","pre actually called");
        data.put("token", idToken[0]);
        //data.put("jokeid",jokeJSON.getString("id"));
        return FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
                .getHttpsCallable("checkIfJokeSaved")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        Log.d("runtimeexception",".then");
                        HashMap result = (HashMap) task.getResult().getData();
                        JSONObject res = new JSONObject(result);
                        String jokeStored = res.getString("jokeStored");
                        Log.d("runtimeexception","jokeStored returned");
                        return jokeStored;
                    }
                });
    }
```

And my code that calls the function::

```
//Code Snippet 2
 try {
      Log.d("runtimeexception","pre checkSavedCall");
      activity.checkIfJokeSavedFirebase().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                        Log.d("runtimeexception","pre task.getResult");
                        Log.d("runtimeexception","task.getResult:" + task.getResult());
                        jokeSaved = Boolean.parseBoolean(task.getResult());
                        String synchronizedChannel = "displaysaved";
                        synchronized (synchronizedChannel){
                            Log.d("runtimeexception","pre notify");
                            synchronizedChannel.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String synchronizedChannel = "displaysaved";
            synchronized (synchronizedChannel){
                try {
                    Log.d("runtimeexception","pre wait");
                    synchronizedChannel.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

My code doesn't make it to the ".then" log in code snippet 1,but when I remove:

```
synchronized (synchronizedChannel){
                try {
                    Log.d("runtimeexception","pre wait");
                    synchronizedChannel.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

from snippet 2,snippet 1 makes it to the ".then" log and completes executing. How is possible that removing a wait() statement results in a call to a firebase function finishing?

Comment: You are probably locking some values in the `onComplete` and it never gets unlocked. But why do you need that code? You are kind of already doing that in the `onComplete` itself.

Comment: I use the wait so that the onPostExecute() doesn't get called before onComplete() is called. And what do you mean by locking values in the onComplete?

Comment: I think what is happening is that the `synchronizedChannel.wait();` is not being fulfilled and because of that the rest of your code is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the solution to the Synchronized problem, but I just switched from AsyncTask to RxJava,and moved the Firebase calls to a Task,which allowed me to get rid of all of the previous synchronized statements,and only required two synchronized statements in the Task.